# Illegal expression: if, then, else statement

Tags: pascal, delphi

I don't understand what's wrong with this code:

```
procedure WebBrowserForm.CheckBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if CheckBox1.Checked = true then
    Button1.Enabled = true else
    Button1.Enabled = false;
end;
```

Could somebody please tell me?

Comment: Instead `if CheckBox1.Checked = true then` it is idiomatic to write `if CheckBox1.Checked then`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code should be

```
procedure WebBrowserForm.CheckBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if CheckBox1.Checked = true then
    Button1.Enabled := true else
    Button1.Enabled := false;
end;
```

In Delphi, the assignment operator is `:=`, while `=` is the comparison operator instead.

BTW, you could write your code more simply as

```
procedure WebBrowserForm.CheckBox1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Button1.Enabled := CheckBox1.Checked;
end;
```